# have to Test Predicated annomymous Class with param of Pagaeble

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Given Below Method want to Test With Junit With MOckit but i tried

```
when(productDataDao.findAll(specObj, PagebleObj)).thanReturn(DummyMOckObj);
```

but this is not working fine. Is there any way to Test Annonymous Class Test with Pagable Object passing in Method Through Mockito?

```
public Page<Product> SearchData(Pageable pageable , ProductDTO proDto) {


        Page<Product> products=  productDataDao.findAll(new Specification<Product>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

                if(null != proDto.getId() && !proDto.getId().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("id"), "%" +proData.getId().trim()) + "%"));
                }

                if(null != proData.getName() && !proData.getName().isEmpty()) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("name"), proData.getName()));
                }

                return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
                predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]) : null);
            }
        }, pageable);
        return products;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
when(productDataDao.findAll(
        ArgumentMatchers.<Specification<Product>>any(), 
        eq(PagebleObj)))
        .thanReturn(DummyMOckObj);
```

You should also inject `productDataDao` mock object in your testing instance.